# JS sound spectrogram drawing : switch from buffer to full file?

Tags: javascript, audio, spectrogram

For a side project I am using the following JS plugin to draw spectrogram of an audio file in the browser :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/spectrogram

```
var spectrogram = require('spectrogram');

var spectro = Spectrogram(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
  audio: {
    enable: false
  }
});

var audioContext = new audioContext();
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', 'audio.mp3', true);
request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

request.onload = function() {
  audioContext.decodeAudioData(request.response, function(buffer) {
    spectro.addSource(buffer, audioContext);
    spectro.start();
  });
};

request.send();
```

(demo available here : https://lab.miguelmota.com/spectrogram/example/)

However, the current code and examples draw the spectrogram "line by line" as the sound is currently playing through buffer.

I wonder if there's a way to actually read the file, then draw the entire spectrogram at once ? I tried converting the array buffer to blob, but the rest of the functions actually expect the sound to be buffered...

So my question is : is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for ? (Draw fulls spectrogram at once instead of buffering the audio and drawing it "on the go"

Is there an easier way to achieve what I'm looking for ?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: i'm using the same package and i was wondering the same thing.. did you figure it out ?